# Laravel eloquent query based on a given time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a simple list of tasks that need to be completed today, at various times. Each task has a reminder/notification that needs to be sent x amount of minutes before it is planned.

Simplified migration is as follows:

```
Schema::create('user_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->time('time'); // The time for when the task has been planned, i.e. 10:00
    $table->string('minutes'); // The minutes before a reminder needs to be send, i.e. 30
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to query only the tasks that are due for a reminder, based on the current time and the `minutes` for the given task. So, for example, I have a task called `sweep the floors` with a value of `30` for the minutes. Which means, 30 minutes before the task is due, I want to send a reminder.

I could query all the tasks and then check for each task if it is due, but I want to query only the tasks that are due for a reminder, obviously.

This is my query so far:

```
$tasks = Task::whereTime('time', '<', Carbon::now()->addMinutes($task->minutes)->format('H:i'))->get();
```

Obviously `$task->minutes` doesn't exist, the value is in the database but I am unsure how to make my query. Any pointers?

Edit:
So I have changed the time column from a `string` to a `time` field, and the query below is the one I am using for testing:

```
$tasks = auth()->user()->tasks()
            ->whereRaw('time < DATE_ADD("' . now() . '", interval 60 minute)')
            ->get();
```

The outcome is this:

[image: Query Log]

I am unsure why the time is displayed below as 0.4. When running the query multiple times I get different results for the time. But I am not sure if the query output is correct, hence the image.

Comment: Dont store numbers in strings, and store times in a TIME not a string. This will make things easier later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to compare column 'time' and current time + column 'minutes'. So basically you need to compare 2 columns. For this instead if whereTime you can use whereRaw(), for example something like this :

```
$tasks = Task::whereRaw('time < DATE_ADD("' . now() . '", interval minutes minute)')->get();
```

**DATE_ADD** is a MySQL function which adds time to it's first parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did play around with this but it only works if the `time` is actually sooner than the current time. It does not add the minutes, also not working when doing something like: `interval 60 minute`. I will keep looking but if you or someone else has any idea why it doesn't add the minutes, please let me know :)

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted the query output as well, perhaps it helps

Comment: I gave the query for minutes as string or int, if you changed it to a time field, query will change as well. I am sorry for not clarifying it.

What query does is select tasks where planned time is sooner than current time + n minutes. So if time = 10:00 and current_time = 11:00, then 11:00 + n will always be more than 10:00, so Where() clause returns always true. but if current_time = 09:00, then it depends on n. If you want to select only tasks which still did not happen, then you need to add ->where('time', '<', now()) to your builder

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that explains a lot :)

Comment: *Edit :
->where('time', '>', now()) , sign was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best way to do this would be by refactoring your table schema to this:

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->time('time'); // The time for when the task has been planned
$table->integer('minutes'); // The minutes before a reminder
$table->time('time_notification');//you can do the query only of this column
$table->timestamps();
```

So you would be able to get them by this query:

```
$tasks = Task::whereTime('time_notification', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('H:i'))->get();
```